# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')

Tags: angular, angular12

Course-Tracker-component.ts

```
students: Student[];

private async getStudents(){
this.students = [];
const data = (await this.studentsService.getStudents());


data.subscribe(
  studentsResponse =>{
    studentsResponse.students.map(s => {
      this.students.push({
        id: s.id,
        first_Name: s.first_Name,
        last_Name:s.last_Name,
        middle_Name:s.middle_Name,
        gender:s.gender,
        dob:s.dob,
        address:s.address,
        email:s.email
      });
    });
  });

  console.log(this.students);
}
```

(Student-Service.ts)

```
export class StudentsService extends HttpclientService{
constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    super(http);
}

public getStudents():Observable<StudentsResponse>{
    return this.get(UniversityAPIUrl.GET_STUDENTS);}
```

(httpclient-service.ts)

```
protected get(relativeUrl: string){
    return this.httpClient.get<any>(this.baseUrl + relativeUrl, { headers:this.getHeaders()});
}
```

(Student.ts)

```
export class Student{
id: number;
first_Name: string;
last_Name:string;
middle_Name:string;
gender:string;
dob:Date;
address:string;
email:string;
}
```

(Student-response.ts)

```
export class StudentsResponse{
    students: Student[];
}
```

In my course-tracker-component.ts I cannot grab the values in the data observable object. All i would like to do is take the result of "const data" and push it into my empty student array which is comprised of student objects.

Comment: First of all you have a weird mix of promise and observable code... so I don't understand why that doesn't throw error? first decide if you are gonna use observables or promises. If we disregard all that... the error says that `studentsResponse.students` is `undefined`, so you need to see what you actually receive from the API, we have no idea of that. You need to do some debugging yourself.

Comment: 0: {id: 1, firstName: "john", lastName: "jones", middle_Name: "jack", gender: "male",...}

Comment: this is what the API returns, a list with a student object in it

Comment: ok,so there isn't actually a `students` property. It is an array you are getting. So where have you decided that it should be `studentsResponse.students.map`? If you are indeed getting an array it should be `studentsResponse.map`

Comment: the StudentsResponse object contains an array called students comprised of Student objects. If i do studentsResponse.map I get an error saying Property 'map' does not exist on type 'StudentsResponse'

Comment: ok, so you have typed your `StudentsResponse` to be an object, but you are telling that what you receive from API is in fact an array? Well, if **that** is the case, then type needs to be an array. You contradict yourself. You say you get an object, but also you wrote that what you get is an array when I asked how the response looks like, so which is it?